# macOS -- Maven environment variable do not take effect

Tags: maven, zsh, zshrc

I'm using zsh as my terminal and trying to install maven, After I tried to set environment variables, the mvn command still prompted:

```
zsh: command not found: mvn
```

I added the following code in my .zshrc file

```
export MAVEN_HOME=/Library/Maven
export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
```

When I execute

```
echo $MAVEN_HOME
```

it shows the variable address exactly. But when I execute

```
echo $PATH
```

There is no address for `Maven` in `PATH`

Comment: Can you share the result of `echo $PATH` before and after you attempt to append `$MAVEN_HOME` to it?

Comment: It doesn't change at all  :(

Comment: The `export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin` statement will absolutely alter the contents of the `PATH` variable.  The fact that you are not seeing any change suggests that something else in your `.zshrc` file or your environment is bypassing or undoing that update. Try adding `echo $PATH` to `~/.zshrc` in multiple spots to trace what is happening.  You can also add `set -x` near  the top of the file to turn on some very verbose logging.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I found that in last line of `.zshrc`, It redefine the `PATH` instead of adding to it, which make my silly mistake.  :)